# Environment variable substitution doesn't work in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

Imagine we have .env file like this:

```
VAR_A=300
VAR_B=$(($VAR_A/100))

VAR_MEM=$((50*$VAR_B))M
```

And my docker-compose file uses it like this:

```
my-service:
  environment:
    SOME_CACHE_VAR: ${VAR_MEM:-100M}
```

When I run the docker-compose it gives me an error:

```
docker.errors.DockerException: Failed converting the string value for memory ($((50*$VAR_B))) to an integer.
```

So, it seems like it doesn't substitute variable at all. How should I do it then?

Comment: What do you think the `$((xxx))` dollar-double-parentheses syntax does in a docker-compose .env file?  (Because I'm pretty sure it doesn't do what you think/hope it does.)

Comment: `(( ... ))` is a [bash](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dblparens.html) thing.  Not a [docker environment replacement](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement) thing, as far as I know.

Comment: @Wyck well, yep, you're right. The thing is I just wanted to show that I'm trying to do it somehow and it doesn't work (because I'm doing it wrong) and I want to know how to do it properly, if it's possible. Neither $(()), nor ${}, nor $() work.

Comment: I'm trying something along the lines of `/bin/bash -c "SOME_CACHE_VAR=((100)) my-service"`, but I don't quite have the syntax right yet.  But the strategy I'm exploring is to replace the service command with a bash command that does the substitutions and then runs the service.  Maybe someone else can figure it out before I do.

Comment: By the way, `VAR_B = ${VAR_A}` "works" in as far as that is the correct substitution syntax.  It just **doesn't do arithmetic**.  You only get _substitution_,  _concatenation_ and the `${variable:-word}` and `${variable:+word}` formations.

Comment: @Wyck thank you for your time. The problem is that I need those transformations in .env file. When I do this: VAR_B=${VAR_A} there, and in the 'environment' section of docker-compose file this: JUST_VAR: ${VAR_B}, I run the system then, enter the docker container, run the command 'env' and finally get this: JUST_VAR=${VAR_A}, not the exact value of it. So, this is the problem I'm trying to solve and maybe the answer is just that you can't substitute variables in the .env file, idk.

Comment: Will those calculations always be fixed?  You expect `VAR_A` to be configurable, but the application needs `SOME_CACHE_VAR` to be set to half its value, and you wouldn't independently set `VAR_B` or `VAR_MEM`?

Comment: FWIW, I don't see what you see: _substitution_ (with no arithmetic) works fine for me.  I have a substitution `JUST_VAR: ${VAR_B}` in the docker-compose.yml file, and I also have both `VAR_B=${VAR_A}` and `VAR_A=123` in the .env file and the dockerfile has `CMD [ "env" ]` and the `env` command correctly displays that `JUST_VAR` has the value `123`.  Maybe you should post your files verbatim?  Could be a syntax problem.  (**NOTE:** I realize you are looking for a .env arithmetic solution, but the docker substitution mechanism doesn't do math.  Still looking for a solution for you.)

Comment: @DavidMaze The result of calculation will vary depending on the number of devices in our system. So, there is one variable which value can be changed, and it should affect other variables.

Comment: @Wyck strange... For me it printed JUST_VAR=${VAR_A}, maybe I had sort of typo, but I am sure that I double checked everything before I wrote my answer here. BTW, because of deadline I came up with the solution I was looking for. I just wrote a Python script that reads the `.env` file, gets a value of variable on which the others depend, does all the calculations and generates new values for other variables. Right after it docker starts all its containers and I get the values I need inside. Maybe it's not the best solution but.. at least it works.. And again thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the actual calculations are fixed and there's only one configurable value, you can do the calculation inside the container, instead of trying to set it up at the Compose level.  Write a shell script to calculate these values, then launch the main container process:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
if [ -n "$VAR_A" ]; then
  VAR_B=$(($VAR_A/100))
  SOME_CACHE_VAR=$((50*$VAR_B))M
else
  SOME_CACHE_VAR=100M
fi
export SOME_CACHE_VAR
exec "$@"
```

Copy this script into your image, and make it be the image's entrypoint.

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh ./
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
CMD (as before)
```

Now when you run the container, you need to supply `$VAR_A`, but not any of the derived variables.  The image's `CMD` or anything you override with Compose `command:` will be run with `$SOME_CACHE_VAR` computed correctly.

```sh
docker run --rm -e VAR_A=1000 my-image sh -c 'echo $SOME_CACHE_VAR'
# Should print "500M"
```

The computed value will not be visible in debugging tools like `docker inspect` or `docker exec`, but the main container process will still see it.

If you can't change the image at all, you can also configure Compose to pass through values from the host environment

```yaml
my-service:
  environment:
    - SOME_CACHE_VAR
```

And you can run the exact same script to compute the value before invoking Compose.

```sh
./entrypoint.sh docker-compose up
```